# Oracle to Postgres Table load using SSIS load performance improvement suggestions?

Tags: postgresql, oracle, ssis, etl, data-migration

I'm trying to load a table from Oracle to Postgres using SSIS, with ~200 million records. Oracle, Postgres, and SSIS are on separate servers.

#### Reading data from Oracle

To read data from the Oracle database, I am using an OLE DB connection using "Oracle Provider for OLE DB". The OLE DB Source is configured to read data using an SQL Command.

In total there are 44 columns, mostly varchar, 11 numeric, and 3 timestamps.

[image]

[image]

#### Loading data into Postgres

To lead data into Postgres, I am using an ODBC connection. The ODBC destination component is configured to load data in batch mode *(not row-by-row insertion)*.

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### SSIS configuration

I created an SSIS package that only contains a straightforward *Data Flow Task*.

[image]

[image]

[image]

#### Issue

The load seems to take many hours to reach even a million count. The source query is giving results quickly while executing in SQL developer. But when I tried to export it threw limit exceeded error.

In SSIS, when I tried to preview the result of the Source SQL command it returned: `The system cannot find message text for message number 0x80040e51 in the message file for OraOLEDB. (OraOLEDB)`

Noting that the source(SQL command) and target table don't have any indexes.

Could you please suggest any methods to improve the load performance?

Comment: You should provide more information about the source and destination schema details, OLE DB Source and OLE DB Destination configurations, connection string... Also, you should clarify if Oracle and Postgres are installed on the same server or not? Is SSIS running on the same server? Do source and destination tables have indexes or not?

Comment: My gut reaction to 'how to improve the performance of SSIS' is to not use SSIS.  My one experience with it, I was presented with a case of copying from Oracle to MSSQL, and it was taking over 4 hours to copy 800k rows.  A trace showed that SSIS was doing row-by-row, slow-by-slow processing.  Took me less than 30 minutes to create a db link from oracle to MSSQL and write a procedure that did a simple 'insert into your_table@mssql (select col1, col2 from my_table)', and the procedure completed in less than 4 minutes.

Comment: @EdStevens SSIS has other options than row-by-row insertion. Using the fast load option will guarantee higher performance. Besides, optimizing the maximum commit size, rows per batch, the buffer size will give you better performance.

Comment: @Hadi - could be. I'll admit that I've never used SSIS myself, and my only experience was the one I described.  The guy that put together the SSIS procedure was well known to see everything through his "Microsoft goggles", even when dealing with oracle.  So I guess I just assumed he knew what he was doing with SSIS.  Your comments, along with other things I observed about him, might suggest he didn't know what he was doing.

Comment: @Hadi, sure.. 1. all 3(Oracle, Postgres & SSIS) are in different servers.. 2. the source(SQL command) and target table don't have any indexes.. 3. attached the screenshots for OLE DB config for source(Oracle) and ODBC connection string config for Destination(Postgres) to the question..

Comment: @Vicky where are the screenshots? I need to see the source an destination editors. Also, how much the source SQL command takes when it is executed in Oracle? Does it have all needed indexes? What are the column types? Can you provide a screenshot of the data flow task properties?

Comment: @Vicky performance tuning requires lot of details that you are not providing.

Comment: @Hadi,  1. I couldn't see any indexes in both source and target table.. 2. the source query while executing in sql developer giving results quickly but when tried to select the dataset the system hangs throwing limit exceeded error.. 3. In total there are 44 columns, mostly varchar, 11 numeric and 3 timestamp.. Please let me know if you need any further details..

Comment: @Hadi, have also attached the screenshot of data flow task properties

Comment: @Vicky what do you mean by "when tried to select the dataset the system hangs throwing limit exceeded error.". Do you mean selecting the table in OLE DB Source rather than using SQL Command?

Comment: I tried to improve and organize your question based on our discussion. I will try to provide an answer to help you tuning the performance of this SSIS package.

Comment: @Hadi, Thanks a lot for your help! Reg the query, what I meant is - the query didn't take much time to execute in SQL developer, but when I tried to export(though its impossible) it threw limit exceeded error. In SSIS, when I tried to preview the result of Source SQL command it returned - "The system cannot find message text for message number 0x80040e51 in the message file for OraOLEDB. (OraOLEDB)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to give some tips to help you improve your package performance. You should start troubleshooting your package systematically to find the performance bottleneck.

*Some provided links are related to SQL Server. No worries! The same rules are applied in all database management systems.*

#### 1. Available resources

First, you should ensure that you have sufficient resources to load the data from the source server into the destination server.

Ensure that the available memory on the source, ETL, and destination servers can handle the amount of data you are trying to load. Besides, make sure that your network connection bandwidth is not decreasing the data transfer performance.

- [How Does SSIS Manage Connection Traffic?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186991/how-does-ssis-manage-connection-traffic)

Make sure that the following hardware issues are not occurring in any of the servers:

1. Drive out of storage
2. Server is out of memory

Make sure that your machine is not running out of memory. You can simply use the Task Manager to identify the amount of available memory.

#### 2. The Data Source

##### Make sure that the table is not a heap

After checking the available resources, you should ensure that your data source is not a heap. At least it would be best if you had a primary key created on that table.

- [Clustered Index vs. Heap in SQL Server](https://www.sqlshack.com/clustered-index-vs-heap/)
- [SQL Server clustered tables vs. Heap tables](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1254/sql-server-clustered-tables-vs-heap-tables/)

##### Indexes

If your SQL Command contains any filtering, ordering, or Joins, you should create the indexes needed by those operations.

- [Use WHERE, JOIN, ORDER BY, SELECT Column Order When Creating Indexes](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3208/use-where-join-orderby-select-column-order-when-creating-indexes/)
- [Is the WHERE-JOIN-ORDER-(SELECT) rule for index column order wrong?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139474/is-the-where-join-order-select-rule-for-index-column-order-wrong)

##### OLE DB provider

Instead of using OLE DB source to connect to Oracle, try using the [Microsoft Connector for Oracle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/oracle-connector?view=sql-server-ver15) *(Previously known as Attunity connectors)*. Microsoft previously mentioned that it should provide faster performance than traditional OLE DB providers.

Use the [Oracle connection manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/oracle-connection-manager?view=sql-server-ver15) rather than OLE DB connection manager.

*To be honest, I am not sure if this component can make the data load faster since I didn't test it before*

##### Removing the destination and adding a dummy task

The last thing to try is to remove the ODBC destination and add any dummy task. For example, use a row count component.

Run the package; if the data is loaded faster, then loading data from Oracle is not decreasing the performance.

#### 3. SSIS configuration

Now, let us start troubleshooting the SSIS package.

##### Running in 64-bit mode

First, try to execute the package in 64-bit mode. You can change this from the package configuration. Make sure that the `Run64bitRuntime` property is set to `True`.

[image]

##### Data flow task buffer size/limits

Using SSIS, data is loaded in memory while being transferred from source to destination. There are two properties in the data flow task that specifies how much data is transferred in memory buffers used by the SSIS pipelines.

[image]

Based on the following [Integration Services performance tuning white paper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/administrator/cc966529(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#EEAA):

> **DefaultMaxBufferRows** – DefaultMaxBufferRows is a configurable setting of the SSIS Data Flow task that is automatically set at 10,000 records.  SSIS multiplies the Estimated Row Size by the DefaultMaxBufferRows to get a rough sense of your dataset size per 10,000 records. You should not configure this setting without understanding how it relates to DefaultMaxBufferSize.

> **DefaultMaxBufferSize** – DefaultMaxBufferSize is another configurable setting of the SSIS Data Flow task. The DefaultMaxBufferSize is automatically set to 10 MB by default. As you configure this setting, keep in mind that its upper bound is constrained by an internal SSIS parameter called MaxBufferSize which is set to 100 MB and can not be changed.

You should try to change those values and test your package performance each time you change them until the package performance increases.

#### 4. Destination

##### Indexes/Triggers/Constraints

You should make sure that the destination table does not have any constraints or triggers since they significantly decrease the data load performance; each batch inserted should be validated or preprocessed before storing it.

- [Are SQL Server database triggers evil?](https://www.sqlshack.com/are-sql-server-database-triggers-evil/)
- [The benefits, costs, and documentation of database constraints](https://www.sqlshack.com/the-benefits-costs-and-documentation-of-database-constraints/)

Besides, the more you have indexes the lower is the data load performance.

##### ODBC Destination custom properties

ODBC destination has [several custom properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/odbc-destination-custom-properties?view=sql-server-ver15) that can affect the data load performance such as `BatchSize` *(Rows per batch)*, `TransactionSize` *(TransactionSize is only available in the advanced editor)*.

- [ODBC connection is very slow](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8cbafee9-ee49-497f-a613-73245665c595/odbc-connection-is-very-slow?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Comment: Thanks so much for your tips and the detailed explanation! will try all the steps and share the results..

Comment: Still working on the combinations to check the performance improvement.. have few queries would be great if you could share some thought on these.. 1. tried using "Microsoft Connector for Oracle" but job failed with Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.. 2. While using date filters in Source SQL command for eg: WHERE loaddt >= '01-Oct-21' and loaddt < '01-Jan-22', no records has been returned from source whereas able to fetch records while querying in SQL developer..

Comment: @Vicky https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/integration-services/error-use-oracle-connection-manager